# Assigning to a slice from another DataFrame requires matching column names?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice

If I want to set (replace) part of a DataFrame with values from another, I should be able to assign to a slice (as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112345/replacing-columns-from-one-dataframe-with-columns-from-another-dataframe-in-pand)) like this:

```
df.loc[rows, cols] = df2
```

Not so in this case, it nulls out the slice instead:

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
   A         B
0  1 -0.240180
1  2 -0.012547
2  3 -0.301475

In [33]: df2
Out[33]: 
   C
0  x
1  y
2  z

In [34]: df.loc[:,'B']=df2

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
   A   B
0  1 NaN
1  2 NaN
2  3 NaN
```

But it does work with just a column (Series) from `df2`, which is not an option if I want multiple columns:

```
In [36]: df.loc[:,'B']=df2['C']

In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
   A  B
0  1  x
1  2  y
2  3  z
```

*Or* if the column names match:

```
In [47]: df3
Out[47]: 
   B
0  w
1  a
2  t

In [48]: df.loc[:,'B']=df3

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
   A  B
0  1  w
1  2  a
2  3  t
```

Is this expected? I don't see any explanation for it in docs or Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. Label alignment is one of the core features of pandas. When you use `df.loc[:,'B'] = df2` it needs to align two DataFrames:

```
df.align(df2)
Out: 
(   A         B   C
 0  1 -0.240180 NaN
 1  2 -0.012547 NaN
 2  3 -0.301475 NaN,     A   B  C
 0 NaN NaN  x
 1 NaN NaN  y
 2 NaN NaN  z)
```

The above shows how each DataFrame looks when aligned as a tuple (the first one is df and the second one is df2). If your df2 also had a column named `B` with values [1, 2, 3], it would become:

```
df.align(df2)
Out: 
(   A         B   C
 0  1 -0.240180 NaN
 1  2 -0.012547 NaN
 2  3 -0.301475 NaN,     A  B  C
 0 NaN  1  x
 1 NaN  2  y
 2 NaN  3  z)
```

Since B's are aligned, your assignment would result in

```
df.loc[:,'B'] = df2

df
Out: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
```

When you use a Series, the alignment will be on a single axis (on index in your example). Since they exactly match, there will be no problem and it will assign the values from `df2['C']` to `df['B']`.

You can either rename the labels before the alignment or use a data structure that doesn't have labels (a numpy array, a list, a tuple...).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the underlying NumPy array:

```
df.loc[:,'B'] = df2.values

df
   A  B
0  1  x
1  2  y
2  3  z
```

Pandas indexing is *always* sensitive to labeling of both rows and columns.  In this case, your rows check out, but your columns do not.  (B != C).

Using the underlying NumPy array makes the operation index-insensitive.

The reason that this *does* work when `df2` is a Series is because Series have no concept of columns.  The only alignment is on the rows, which are aligned.